# Junit with @Parameters to test data from file

Tags: java, oracle, junit

I am trying to read data from a file and use the data for testing the procs. Even the proc to be tested is determined from the contents of the file.

Sample.txt is the file from which I read the data, the file contains the following data

```
testproc=sample_check('N')
output=yes
type=function
testproc=sample_check('N')
output=yes
type=function
testproc=sample_check('N')
output=yes
type=function
```

The below program tries to read the file and populate its contents into a 2 dimensional String array.

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class Testdata extends Testdb {

    public String expected;
    public String actual;

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<String[]> getTestParameters() {
        String param[][] = new String [3][3];
        String temp[] = new String [3];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));
            String strLine;
            String methodkey       = "testproc";
            String methodtypekey   = "type";
            String methodoutputkey = "output";
            String method = "";
            String methodtype = "";
            String methodoutput = "";

            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, "=");
                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    String key = st.nextToken();
                    String val = st.nextToken();
                    if (key.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(methodkey))
                    {
                        method = val.trim();
                        temp[j] = "SELECT " + method + " FROM dual";
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if (key.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(methodoutputkey))
                    {
                        methodoutput = val.trim();
                        temp[j] = methodoutput;
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if (key.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(methodtypekey))
                    {
                        methodtype = val.trim();
                        if (methodtype.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("function"))
                        {
                            System.out.println(i + " " + method);
                            param[i] = temp;
                            i++;
                            j = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return Arrays.asList(param)           ;
    }

    public Testdata(String[] par) {
        this.expected = par[0];
        this.actual = par[1];
    }

    @Test
    public void test_file_data() //throws java.io.IOException
    {
        testString("Output should be"+expected , expected, actual);
    }


}
```

I receive an error 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

testString is a method that connects to the database to check if the actual value tallies with the expected result. This takes two string values as argument.

My question is how should 
return Arrays.asList(param)
and method 
public Testdata(String[] par)
look like?

I tested using this and it works fine but since I read from a file, I want to use an array which needs to be returned using return Arrays.asList

```
return Arrays.asList(new String[][]{
            { "yes", "SELECT sample_check('N') FROM dual"},
            { "yes", "SELECT sample_check('N') FROM dual"},
            { "yes", "SELECT sample_check('N') FROM dual"}
    })           ;
}

public Testdata(String expected,
                           String actual) {
    this.expected = expected;
    this.actual = actual;
}
```

Any advice on getting this working?

Comment: where is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException being thrown?

Comment: Also, rather than using arrays for param and temp, I think it would be easier to use a Collection such as ArrayList.  I have a suspicion that param isn't being set correctly and could be where the trouble is happening.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)                                                                                                               Regarding using a Collection, will I be able to use 2-dimensional collection similar to the String[][] array above? The reason is Testdata requires two string values which needs to be an array or similar for each testcase and since there would be multiple testcases, it requires a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList> arrList2D = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(2);  arrList2D.add(new ArrayList()); arrList2D.add(new ArrayList());

Comment: Also, just as a side note, you may be able to refactor your if...else if...else if block with polymorphism.  Are you familiar with refactoring?  If so, I'm referring to "Replace Conditional with Polymorphism".  That's just a side note, though, and might just add complexity to your test...

Comment: Just did some further reading on parameterized tests.  Your Collection elements in getTestParameters have to have arrays of identical length (like in your example that works at the bottom of your question).  Also, the array length must match the number of arguments in the constructor.  So, looks like you need 3 strings in your constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor is wrong. You need the same number of parameters that you have items in your `String[]`

```
public Testdata(String[] par) {
    this.expected = par[0];
    this.actual = par[1];
}
```

This should be:

```
public Testdata(String expected, String actual, String somethingElse) {
    this.expected = expected;
    this.actual = actual;
}
```

See the [javadoc for Parameterized](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html):

> For example, to test a Fibonacci function, write:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
    @Parameters
    public static List<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }
        });
    }

    private int fInput;
    private int fExpected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        fInput= input;
        fExpected= expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
    }
}
```

> Each instance of FibonacciTest will be constructed using the
>   two-argument constructor and the data values in the @Parameters
>   method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That was exactly the issue .. Using "public Testdata(String expected, String actual, String somethingElse) {     this.expected = expected;     this.actual = actual; }" fixed it